# Split string column based on number of characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in a dataframe:

```
columnA
EUR590
USD680
EUR10000,9
USD40
```

how can i split it based on the first three characters, that the dataframe looks like:

```
columnA columnB
590     EUR
680     USD
10000,9  EUR
40       USD
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df['columnB']=df['columnA'].str.slice(stop=3)
df['columnA']=df['columnA'].str.slice(start=3)
```

Comment: partly correct, the columnA looks still like the original column

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a pattern:

```
df1=df.columnA.str.extract('(?P<columnA>.{3})(?P<columnB>.{1,})')
print(df1)
```

---

```
  columnA  columnB
0     EUR      590
1     USD      680
2     EUR  10000,9
3     USD       40
```

Regex graph below:

[image: Regex graph]

Comment: this only works for a dataframe with one column or? what if I have other columns (which should be untouched) in my dataframe?

Comment: @PV8 you mean you want to to this for other columns too?, can you update the example with another col and how do you want the split to happen.. little confused here.

Comment: if I run the command df1=..`` i will only have a dataframe with columnA and columnB, but my original dataframe consists of columnC and more...

Comment: @PV8 : in that case you can use `df.pop('columnA').str.extract('(?P<columnA>.{3})(?P<columnB>.{1,})').join(df)` this will delete columnA from the df and give you 2 col df, which you can join back to the original df.